# Why does the following code to insert a node at the end of a singly linked list does not work?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Below is the code in C language:

function call:

```
insert(&head,value);

void insert(struct node** headref,int value)
{
    struct node* head = (*headref); 

    while( head!=NULL )
     {

        head= head->link;
     }

    struct node* new_node=(struct node*)malloc( sizeof(struct node) );

    new_node->data=value;
    new_node->link=NULL;

    head=new_node;  
}
```

Comment: How is the list supposed to know about the new element? You'd have to set the `link` member of the last item in the list to point to the new element. Once `head` becomes NULL, you've lost the element whose `link` member you need to set. A better loop terminating condition would be `while (head->link != NULL)`

Comment: I suggest you never move your `head` as it is not recommended !! It is a reference pointer which should always point to the starting node in the linked list. Use some other pointer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link the last element of the list to `new_node` otherwise you will loose the linked-ness(if there is such a word :) ) of your list. You need to store 2 pointers in the cycle - `head`, that you already have and a pointer to the previous element(the element before head). Take special care for the case where you have empty list!

Answer (score 0):

```
  while( head!=NULL )
 {
    head= head->link;
 }
```

At the end of this loop `head` would be `NULL`.You might want to stop at the last node

```
  while( head->link!=NULL )
 {
    head= head->link;
 }
```

and then do something like

```
head->link = new_node;
```

Now you have to take extra care if the list is empty because then `head->link` will throw error if `head=NULL`.
You can place a check in the beginning like

```
//allocate new_node here
if(head==NULL)
{
   *headref = new_node; //Note only in this case would headref ever change
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the last node `head` with `new_node` which is not expected. Loop till last node and make the `head->link` to point to `new_node` as shown below:

```
insert(&head,value);

void insert(struct node** headref,int value)
{
    struct node* head = (*headref); 

    while( head->link !=NULL )
     {

        head= head->link;
     }

    struct node* new_node=(struct node*)malloc( sizeof(struct node) );

    new_node->data=value;
    new_node->link=NULL;

    head->link=new_node;  
}
```

Comment: so you are inserting that element after the `head` node? Am I right?

Comment: yes.. At the end of the `while` loop, `head` node will be pointing to the last node of the linked list. And `new_node` will be inserted after the `head` node.

Comment: Ok ! Lets take a scenario in which there are 5 elements and the `head` is pointing to the first element. After the `new_node` is inserted (after the `head` according to you logic), to which node will the `new_node` be pointing to? I see that your `new_node->link=NULL`. I guess there will be some effect !

Comment: There is a `while` loop in my example where i traverse till the end of the list by doing `head=head->link;` and then only i insert the `new_node`

Comment: If the list is empty `head->link` will be `NULL->link`.This will fail

Answer (score 0):

Logic mistake. Try this.

```
struct node* new_node=(struct node*)malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
new_node->data=value;
new_node->link=NULL;

if (!head)
{
   head = new_node;
   return;
}

// Use for or while loop as below.
// 1. for(;head->link;head=head->link); 
// or  
/* 2. */
while (head->link)
{
    head = head->link;
}
head->link = new_node;
```

Better to rename head with some meaningful name!

Comment: You are not reflecting change in `headref`

Answer (score 0):

In the function local variable `head` is assigned to the new created node. After exiting the function this local variable will be destroyed and the original list will not be changed.

Moreover this loop

```
while ( head != NULL )
{
    head = head->link;
}
```

does not make sense. In fact it can be substituted for

```
head = NULL;
```

The function can look as it is shown in the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

int insert( struct node **head, int value )
{
    struct node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        tmp->data = value;
        tmp->link = NULL;

        while ( *head ) head = &( *head )->link;

        *head = tmp;
    }

    return success;
}

void display( struct node*head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->link ) printf( " %d", head->data );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    const int N = 10;
    struct node *head = NULL;

    int i = 0;
    while ( i < N && insert( &head, i ) ) i++;

    display( head );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```